# Why wget fails to download a file but browser succeeds?

Tags: http, browser, wget

I am trying to download virus database for clamav from `http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd` location. I am able to download `main.cvd` from web browser(chrome or firefox) but unable to do same with `wget` and get the following error:

```
--2021-05-03 19:06:01--  http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
Resolving database.clamav.net (database.clamav.net)... 104.16.219.84, 104.16.218.84, 2606:4700::6810:db54, ...
Connecting to database.clamav.net (database.clamav.net)|104.16.219.84|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-05-03 19:06:01 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Any lead on this issue?

**Edit 1:**

This is how my chrome cookies look like when I try to download `main.cvd`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any lead on this issue?*

It might be possible that blocking is based on `User-Agent` header. You might use `--user-agent=` option to set same `User-Agent` as for browser. Example

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" https://www.example.com
```

will download example.com page and identify itself as Firefox to server. If you want know more about `User-Agent`'s part meaning you might read [Developer Mozilla docs for User-Agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: Thanks. it worked out, `wget` with `--user-agent` option. Do you have any idea of how can I pass same option in SRC_URI variable of yocto recipe?

Comment: @RaxeshOriya no, I do not know tool named *yocto recipe*

Answer (score 0):

Check for the session cookies or tokens from browser, as some websites place similar kind of security

Comment: I am unable to make anything out from browser cookie, I edited my question with cookie.